# Using Outline for CSS borders

Tags: css

has anyone else used outline in CSS to create double borders instead of nested divs? What are the pitfalls of using outline in CSS because I doesn't seem very popular??
Cheers

Comment: Why is this jquery, html5 tagged?

Comment: If you want two borders, you should have a look at the `double` border style. Or if you don't like that and you want multiple borders without nested divs, styling the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements may be the way to go. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/62QHG/) I made the other day, with 1 div.

Comment: I tagged jQuery/HTML as I figured specialists in that area will know CSS moderately well I think, I am a newbie here so diddnt realise how fast the responses are

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean instead of two divs with single solid border?

The cons for this, as i've noticed, is that you can't control each color, they both have to be the same...Also, you can't control their distance apart, or each of their sizes etc.

So I think it really depends on what you'll be using a double border for...but for simple double standard borders, it alot quicker than making two divs and two borders...(IMO)

I think they're not popular because how often do you see double borders on the web?

Comment: I mean if I wanted to have a double border on a div id="slideshow", normally i nest another div class="inner" and give it a colour #fff then my div id="slideshow" has a border #000 for example and this creates a double border illusion. However, I can use border #000 and outline #fff; on div id="slideshow" to create a double border illusion without a need to nest div class="inner", however what are the pitfalls of working this way?

Comment: Ya I don't know of any problems with that. When I read your question I mistakenly thought you were asking about border: double, but what you have _seems_ fine.

Comment: Thanks! didnt realise I could use double:border either, thanks a million :)

Comment: No problem! glad to help. just put border: double 4px red; (for example)
There's a whole list of them [click HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It depends. `outline` works pretty well in most browsers including IE8, quick example http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jecEB/.

You could also use `box-shadow` for same purpose and you can add more than 2 borders. Of course, this will only work in browsers that support this css3 feature.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with outline is that it's outside of the box-model, so it can cause some ugly collapsing.

Moreover, outline is used a lot for accessibility features, and it's always a good idea not to mess with accessibility.

Comment: How is it used for accessibility, do you ever use outline yourself?

Comment: Some browser use outline in default styles. Per exemple Chrome uses outline for :focus styles. I think Opera Mobile also uses Outline a lot. Myself I often use it to add hints for visually impaired people.